# Kornia rotation not quite rotating as expected

Tags: python, rotation, pytorch, tensor

I'm trying to use the [kornia.geometry.transform.rotate](https://kornia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/geometry.transform.html) function, in Python, to rotate a [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/) tensor by arbitrary angles. However if I do a simple 90 degree rotation, the resulting tensor doesn't look like it's been fully rotated.

Here's some sample code:

```
import torch 
from kornia.geometry.transform import rotate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = torch.ones((1,64,64))
a[0,:,2] += 1

angle = torch.tensor([90])

c = rotate(a,angle)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(a[0].detach().numpy())
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(c[0].detach().numpy())
```

And the results before and after the rotation:

[image]

Am I missing a subtlety due to the tensor being too coarse here, which causes interpolation issues or something that would be alleviated with a much finer grained tensor?

Many thanks in advance!

---

**Note** I am using:

- python 3.6.10
- kornia 0.2.0
- pytorch 1.4.0

Answer (score 1):

to use Kornia, you can use the [`Rotate` class](https://torchgeometry.readthedocs.io/en/latest/geometry.transform.html#kornia.geometry.transform.Rotate).

Below is an example to rotating all tensors in a mini-batch by a fixed 45 degrees:

```
import kornia as tgm

# set the rotation angles - assume batch size is N; 
angle = torch.tensor([45]*N).cuda()

# do the rotation:
tensor_rotated = tgm.Rotate(angle)(tensor_input)
```

The only caveat right now is that it seems super-slow..

Hope this helps!